# Calculate hourly and daily average of 3 years time series data with 5 minute without excluding the NA values

Tags: r

i have three years time series data with 5 minute interval time  now i want to calculate the hourly and daily average of this data sets without excluding the NA values and also want to plot the time series.My data set is as follows:

```
Date       Time     Temp   Pre humidity Rainfall Windspd
2014-01-01 00:00:05  NA    1002 100        350    30
2014-01-01 00:00:10  30    1000  80         NA     NA
..........  ......
.........   .......
.........   .......
2015-12-31  23:55:00  ..   ...    ...       ...    ...
```

Comment: Just do one of the group by operations. i.e  `library(dplyr) ; library(lubridate); df1 %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time))) %>% group_by(Daily = as.Date(Date)) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0):

First, create reproducible example (which you should have done to make it easier for people to help you) - I supposed you were talking about 5-seconds (not minutes) intervals and reduced the time extent:

```
myDate = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:05"), 
                    as.POSIXct("2014-07-31 23:55:00"), 
                    by='5 sec')
N = length(myDate)
df = data.frame(Date = myDate,
                Temp = runif(N, 5, 35),
                Pre = runif(N, 800, 1200),
                humidity = runif(N, 0, 100),
                Rainfall = runif(N, 100, 500),
                Windspd = runif(N, 0, 50))

set.seed(13)
df$Temp[sample(1:N, 1000)] = NA
df$Pre[sample(1:N, 500)] = NA
df$humidity[sample(1:N, 10000)] = NA
df$Rainfall[sample(1:N, 4000)] = NA
df$Windspd[sample(1:N, 8000)] = NA
```

What you wan to achieve can be efficiently done with `dplyr` by first `grouping` your data by the time step you are interested in and `summarizing` your grouped data to apply a function (here, `mean`).
For the daily average, it is quite easy: just take a grouping variable by day.
For the hourly average, you can `cut` your data using breaks from a 5-min sequence (you might want to adapt the min and max of that sequence...).

```
library(dplyr)

daily = df %>% group_by(Daily = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=T)))

hourseq = seq.POSIXt(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by='1 hour')
hourly = df %>% group_by(Hourly = cut(Date, breaks=hourseq)) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=T)))
```